# I keep finding batteries and I can't pick them up. Why?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I keep finding batteries but I can't pick them up. What are they for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Batteries instantly recharge your spacebar item. If you don't have one, or your spacebar item is already fully charged, you can't pick them up.